# Capture android screen for text

Tags: android

Im trying to build an app that can copy and save all text that user selected in any othe apps such as chrome, adobe reader, sms .....
In fact I have no idea how should I do that or even is that possible or not
I will be thankful if any one can help me.

Comment: Well, Android OS has implemented all that things for you. No need to write your own soft.

Comment: Take a look at this; https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Comment: @AndriiAbramov can you please give me an example?

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear. I uploaded a picture in below to clarify. http://uupload.ir/files/y27p_untitled.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Accessibility API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/index.html) allows you to investigate the view hierarchy displayed on the screen and read text from different views. On top of that, you may be able to fetch the coordinates of where user tapped (maybe by using some kind of [system overlay view](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/24/system-alert-window-now-more-hidden-than-ever.html)) and translate them to the position of text the user most likely wanted to copy. Note that if this even works at usable level, will be very hacky and most likely making it work across considerable number of devices will be hard.

Comment: I want it to accessible in any app, for example when user selected a text in chrome, Adobe reader a little menu appear(like picture I send previus) and save the text in my app.

Comment: I think you might be able to use [addPrimaryClipChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html#addPrimaryClipChangedListener(android.content.ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener) to detect when user selects and copies text to the clipboard. Then you can use mentioned system overlay view to display your menu and save the text in your app. Please upvote useful answers.

Comment: ClipChanged is for data which is copied .
my problem is about monitoring other apps.
for example assume you opened you chrome browser and select a word.
now I want my app opens as menu.

Comment: Any idea? Is that even possible in android ?